# datetime in C# vs, SQL and GETDATE() from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I use `GETDATE()` in a SQL Server stored procedure to insert a date into the SQL Server database table.

After that I need to implement a C# function which is based on `datetime` input parameter finds if the date was saved in the tables.

The datetime in C# and SQL are different. How do I convert from C# datetime to SQL datetime which has a form of `yyyy-mm-ddT:yy:mm:ss.mmm`? I need to specify explicitly `yyyy-mm-ddT:yy:mm:ss.mmm`.

Will be happy for all propositions/possible ways.

Comment: I'm not sure what the format has to do with the comparison at all?

Comment: No, `DATETIME` in T-SQL and `DateTime` in .NET are **not** different - you can represent **any** `DATETIME` in SQL Server as a .NET `DateTime`. `DATETIME` in SQL Server has limits in terms of range (1-Jan-1753 to 31-Dec-9999) and accuracy (3.33ms) but it's deprecated in SQL Server **2008** anyway and shouldn't be used anymore; use `DATE` (if you only need date - no time) or `DATETIME2(n)` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` in .Net framework and SQL Server *(if it is DateTime type field)* is irrespective of the format. Format is only useful for displaying output.

If your field in SQL Server is of `DateTime` type  then you can query it from C# code using parameterized query something like:

```
public DataTable GetRecords(DateTime dtParameter)
{
    DataTable dt = null;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from yourTable where DateField = @dateparameter"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateparameter",dtParameter);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //...rest of the code
            dt.Load(dr);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: the datetime should be argument provided by user

Comment: @Yakov, thats fine you, you can replace `DateTime.Now` with the parameter passed by user. It should be of type `DateTime` in .Net framework.

Comment: @Yakov, format doesn't matter. What is the type of field in SQL table ?

Comment: @Yakov :: If you are taking the value from user, you can simply parse it into a datetime object. here is a nice article. http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse

Comment: Are you asking your user to provide seconds and millisecond?

Comment: I saved datetime.I see that in sql table is saved for example2014-01-13 16:53.00.121.How do I transfer that in C#

Comment: @DanBracuk-How can I ask him?I just defined an input from the type System.datetime.So the format which is proposed to the user is like 1/14/2014 4:44 PM

Comment: @Yakov, the format you see is based on your locale settings, When you will compare it in database then the display format doesn't matter, both `1/14/2014 4:44 PM` and `2014-1-14 16:44` are same.

Comment: @Habib - unfortunately you misunderstand the question - I ask about ss.mmm part (second ....

Comment: @Yakov, you can create `DateTime` object in C# like: `DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 01, 14, 16, 44, 00, 121);` that will have seconds and milliseconds as per your requirement. If you are going to show the result returned back from Sql server then populate a .Net framework `DateTime` type field and then display the result in required format like: `string formattedDate = dt.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @Habib - How can my user enter the DateTime in the format having sec and milisec?

Comment: @Yakov, that is upto you, you can get a string from the user and use `DateTime.ParseExact`, you can use DatePicker controls based on the type of application you are targeting, you can read strings separately for Date/Hour/Minutes/seconds/MS and then convert them to integer and use the `DateTime` constructor. There are many ways. But it mainly depends on the application you are targeting.

Comment: @Habib - it is wcf.The user shoul enter the parameter of the type as I specified in the appropriate method .It is System.DateTime.I want to know how the user fills the fiel of datetime including seconds and miliseconds

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45210/discussion-between-yakov-and-habib)

Answer (score 4):

Datetimes between C# and SQL are 100% compatible.  The format shouldn't make any difference *if you are passing them as `DateTime`s*.  If you are generating a SQL string then I would highly recommend changing to SQL Parameters so you don;t have to worry about any formatting issues.

Answer (score 2):

A `datetime` has no format at all, it has a value. [SQL-DateTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) and C# [DateTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are compatible. So don't convert it (to `string`) at all but pass it as datetime-parameter to the database.

Then you're safe if the `DateTime` value is within [`SqlDateTime.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue.aspx)(January 1, 1753) and [`SqlDateTime.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.maxvalue.aspx)(December 31, 9999).

Comment: I`ve passed the value.But the sql store procedure doesn`t find this value in the tables.Besides that it is in.Probably the seconds part is missing

Answer (score 2):

You should never write `DateTime.Now` from client code to insert into the database as this will be based on the clients local time; do this

```
public DateTime GetDatabaseTime()
{
    var parameter = new SqlParameter("time", SqlDbType.DateTime2)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var command = new SqlConnection("SELECT @time = SYSDATETIME()", connection))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    return (DateTime)parameter.Value;
}
```

Also you should never use `DATETIME` in SQL Server you should always use `DATETIME2` as `DATETIME` is less accurate than `C#::DateTime` and it will lead to rounding errors. I know this from bitter experience.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Entity Framework, and your database is using datetime and not datetime2, the trick is to use SqlDateTime to match the fact that .Net goes to nanosecond, versus sql's millisecond precision.  You can use your DateTime variable in .net.. for a SqlDateTime instance, and then you can uniquely identify a record down to the millisecond.

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime entry2 = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(new DateTime(dto.LookUpDateTime));
DateTime entry = entry2.Value;

var existticket = from db in context.Tickets
                              where db.LookupDateTime == entry && db.UserId == UserId
                              select db;
```